# How to check every field in a table is nt substring of a field in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

My scheme looks like:
I have two tables: `table1`, `table2`
`table1` has one field: `table1-name` of type string.
`table2` has one field: `table2-name` of type string.

I want to return all rows of `table1-name` that are NOT substring of any `table2-name` records. I did:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `table2-name`.`table2`
FROM `table2`, `table1`
WHERE `table2-name`.`table2` NOT IN (SELECT `table1-name` FROM `table1`)
LIMIT 100;
```

But this returns all `table2-name` that are not equal to `table1-name`. What I need is all `table2-name`that are not sub-string of `table2-name`.

Example:

`table1-name`:aa.abc.com, bb.com, xyz.com

`table2-name`: abc.com, aaa.com, xyz.com

The query above will return:

```
abc.com
aaa.com
```

What I want to return is:
`aaa.com`

I do not want `abc.com` to be returned because it is a sub-string of `aa.abc.com`.

Can you correct my query?

Comment: You'll need `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. What is your DBMS? MySQL and SQL Server are different products. You tagged both.

Comment: I am typing and executing queries in `mysql-workbench` installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes. I use mysql syntax.

Comment: Please don't use '-' as a table/column identifier. It's fantastically dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

Use `NOT EXISTS` for such conditions:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists
(
  select *
  from table2 t2
  where t2.`table2-name` like concat('%', t1.`table1-name`, '%')
);
```

BTW: You should avoid names like `table2-name` where you need quotes in order to use them. Use something like `table2_name` instead.

Comment: I think you mean `like` not `not like`?? because I need to query those that not in the result of the query where there is substring? or am I missing something?

Comment: @user9371654: You are right of course. I've corrected my mistake.

Comment: unfortunately my dataset is tool large so I did not get the query result in a reasonable time and so I can not confirm if the answer is correct. I have to test it in smaller tables though.

Comment: A string operation to compare substrings is costly and so the query takes very long on big tables. This is not surpising. Is there a pattern that can help? In your example it's always the end of the string you are comparing. Is this true also for your real data?

Answer (score 2):

If `table2` is not very big, I wonder how this would perform:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select group_concat(t2.name separator '|') as names
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
where t1.name not regexp t2.names;
```

Or, equivalently:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select group_concat(t2.name) as names
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
where find_in_set(t1.name, t2.names) = 0;
```

This assumes that `t2.name` does not have special characters (for `regexp`) or commas (for `find_in_set()`).

Comment: Table 2 is big (2-3 million record). I am currently using @Thorsten Kettner query and it seems going forever.

Comment: @user9371654 . . . Well, this will definitely not work on such a large table.  This may not be something that you can do efficiently in MySQL.

Comment: thanks. I have two files with name in each line. I want to query all file 1 names that are not equal and are not substring of file2 names. Are there any other choices than MySQL? do you think Linux tools can do better job? Can you provide Linux commands to do this

Comment: You might have luck with Python, if the values fit in memory.  You could use an n-gram index (supported by Postgres) or develop one yourself.  String subsetting is computationally intensive.

Answer (score 1):

To check if something is a substring of something else, you would need to use either 'LIKE' (as shown below) or possibly 'REGEXP_LIKE'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.*
FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 where table1.table1name LIKE CONCAT('%',table2.table2name,'%') > 0)
LIMIT 100;
```

On another note 
1 - your problem description is not consistent (you confuse table1 and table2 repeatedly), choosing a better name would likely help with that.
2 - as you will see, I've taken the liberty of renaming the columns to drop the '-' character.

Another version that will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.*
FROM table2
WHERE table2name NOT IN (SELECT table2.table2name FROM table1 where table1.table1name like CONCAT('%',table2.table2name,'%') > 0)
LIMIT 100;
```

Please check the [SQLFiddle (I also copied Thorsten Kettner's version above in there after renaming tables/columns)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/303024/9)