# mysql Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 't2'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench and mysql server to query databse. I have two tables `t1` and `t2` with one column `t1_name` and `t2_name`. t2 has 3 million records and t1 has 1 million.

I need to select all `t2_names` where `t2_names` are not equal to `t1_name` or not substring of `t1_name`. When I try the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t2_name`
FROM `t2`, `t1`
`t2`.`t2_name` NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',`t1`.`t1_name`,'%'));
```

I get this error:

> mysql Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 't2'

Can you explain and correct my query please? Previously I have made [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578759/how-to-check-every-field-in-a-table-is-nt-substring-of-a-field-in-another-table#51580032) and tried this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t2_name`
FROM `t2`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `t1`
                    WHERE `t2_name` LIKE CONCAT('%',`t2_name`,'%'));
```

but it takes forever and never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Start by qualifying all column names.  Does this still cause an error?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.t2_name
FROM t2 JOIN
     t1
     ON t2.t2_name NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.t1_name, '%');
```

If your issue is performance, the `not exists` is going to be better without the `distinct`:

```
SELECT t2_name
FROM t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t1
                  WHERE t2.t2_name LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.t1_name, '%')
                 );
```

However, this is not going to be much of an improvement.  Unfortunately, `like` queries with such wildcards are highly inefficient.  Often, you can structure the data model so you can write a more efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `WHERE` keyword. The parser thinks `t2` should be an alias for `t1` as it follows `t1`. But `t2` is already occupied by the previous `t2`.

Insert `WHERE` (and remove the last closing `)`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t2_name`
FROM `t2`, `t1`
WHERE `t2`.`t2_name` NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',`t1`.`t1_name`,'%');
```

Side note: I'm afraid your attempt with building the Cartesian product won't perform any any better than the `NOT EXISTS`. More likely it performs much, much worse...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistyped the second where clause and it should say

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t2_name`
FROM `t2`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `t1`
                    WHERE `t1_name` LIKE CONCAT('%',`t2_name`,'%'));
```

At the moment you are effectively comparing t2_name with itself.

It's going to be jolly slow anyway because mysql is going to do a table scan on that. Have a look at your data structure and content and see whether you might be better doing some data cleansing/restructuring before you start trying to use it for analysis.